# Setting timeout for c/c++ function call

Tags: c++, timeout

Suppose my main function calls an external function veryslow()

```
int main(){... veryslow();..}
```

Now I would like to the invocation part of very_slow in main, so that veryslow terminates if it runs out of a time bound. Something like this

```
int main(){... call_with_timeout(veryslow, 0.1);...}
```

What is a simple way to achieve that? My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Modify `veryslow()` to take a duration as a parameter, then bail from it when necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call this function in a new thread, and set a timeout to terminate the thread, it will end this function call.

A POSIX example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

pthread_t tid;

// Your very slow function, it will finish running after 5 seconds, and print Exit message.
// But if we terminate the thread in 3 seconds, Exit message will not print.
void * veryslow(void *arg)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "Enter veryslow...\n");
    sleep(5);
    fprintf(stdout, "Exit veryslow...\n");

    return nullptr;
}

void alarm_handler(int a)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "Enter alarm_handler...\n");
    pthread_cancel(tid);    // terminate thread
}

int main()
{
    pthread_create(&tid, nullptr, veryslow, nullptr);

    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
    alarm(3);   // Run alarm_handler after 3 seconds, and terminate thread in it

    pthread_join(tid, nullptr); // Wait for thread finish

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An idea, and a good one, but needs more detail to be a useful answer.

Comment: Yes, I didn't give actual code example because OP didn't specify the OS he is using. Thread related APIs are different in different OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `future` with timeout.

```
std::future<int> future = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){ 
    veryslow();
});

std::future_status status;

status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

if (status == std::future_status::timeout) {
    // verySlow() is not complete.
} else if (status == std::future_status::ready) {
    // verySlow() is complete.
    // Get result from future (if there's a need)
    auto ret = future.get();
}
```

Note that there's no built-in way to cancel an async task. You will have to implement that inside `verySlow` itself.

See here for more:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for

Comment: *"there's no built-in way to cancel an async task"*  
So what's the benefit of using a `future` in this case ?  That just makes it more complicated.

Comment: @SidS: Well, you are free to continue and ignore the invocation. And the calling thread doesn't block. Basically, you get all the benefits of async programming.

Comment: But it's still running.  The question was how to make it stop running, after some time.

Comment: @SidS: The best idea would be to modify `verySlow` itself then. It's never a good idea to kill a thread, but if you insist, run `verySlow` in a thread, wait for timeout in calling thread, and then kill thread if it's still running.

Comment: I agree, the best idea is to modify `veryslow()`.  No call for multithreading in this case.

Comment: I think `std::future::wait_until()` would be more appropriate for this problem. Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_until , which gives an example on how to explicitly timeout a function call (using `std::future` and `std::promise`).

Answer (score 0):

i would pass a pointer to an interface into the function and ask for one back. with this i would enable two way communication to perform all necessary tasks--including timeout and timeout notification.